# How can i find the variance of ATE by using g computation without bootstraping?

Tags: causality, treatment-effect

I have a binary treatment and binary outcome and have estimated the average treatment effect (ATE) by using g-computation, which involves training a model for the outcome given the covariates and treatment, generating predicted values by setting the treatment to 1 and then to 0, and taking the average of the differences between the predicted values. Most sources recommend using bootstrapping to estimate the variance of the resulting estimate. Is it possible to get the variance without bootstrapping?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please define "ATE" and "g computation".

Comment: Did you use machine-learning or parametric models to estimate the conditional means? For the latter, you can bootstrap but the estimates may be biased for the true ATE. For the former, bootstrap does not work (at all).

Comment: If you're estimating ATE via $g$-computation using a simple linear regression model: $E(y_i)=\beta_0 + \beta_1 t_i + \beta_2 x_i + ...$, with no interaction terms containing $t_i$, then the expected ATE is the coefficient $\beta_1$ and the variance for ATE can be computed from the coefficient's standard error (which may be found in the regression output in whichever program you're using).

Comment: For more complex regression models, if you want to avoid bootstrapping I suggest using the delta method to estimate the ATE variance. However, I don't know the delta method formula for $g$-computation - will have to either derive or find in the literature.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a parametric outcome regression model like logistic regression, you can estimate the ATE as an average marginal effect, e.g., using the `margins` package in R or the `margins` function in Stata. These procedures use the delta method to compute the variance of the ATE.

It may also be possible to use an empirical Bayes approach, which is similar to bootstrapping in that you have to resample and compute the effect many times, but instead of sampling before fitting the model, you sample from the fitted model. That is, you assume the coefficients follow a multivariate normal distribution (which is asymptotically true), and from each draw of the coefficients, you compute the ATE for all units. The distribution of the ATE across all the coefficient draws is its sampling distribution, the variance of which can serve as the variance for the ATE. This is described in the context of mediation analysis by [Imai, Keele, and Tingley (2010)](https://doi.org/10.1037/a0020761) and in the context of propensity score matching by [Austin, Rubin, and Thomas (2021)](https://doi.org/10.1002/sim.9141) (and probably others).

If you didn't use a parametric model and instead used a machine learning method to estimate the potential outcomes, there is no straightforward to estimate the variance of the ATE after g-computation. However, if you construct a doubly robust estimator like augmented inverse probability weighting (AIPW) or targeted minimum loss-based estimation (TMLE), you can use the influence function to estimate the variance. The influence functions for these estimators are functions only of the predicted values (i.e., the estimated potential outcomes and propensity scores). However, my understanding is that for the standard versions of both estimators, inference is not doubly robust, even though the effect estimate is; that is, both models need to be correct for the influence function to provide a valid estimate of the variance. There may be some robust versions of these methods that allow for doubly robust variance estimation as well, but they are somewhat arcane.